# Jupyter Notebook ImportError: cannot import name ‘soft_unicode’ from ‘markupsafe’ in WSL2 for windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't find the way to go around this error. I am trying to run `jupyter notebook` on my WSL2 on VScode and get the following error:

```
  File "/home/augustov/.local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "/home/augustov/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.serverapp import flags
  File "/home/augustov/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 37, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/nodes.py", line 23, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 656, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/home/augustov/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

I found a previous post with a similar problem [here](https://techoverflow.net/2022/04/07/how-to-fix-jupyter-lab-importerror-cannot-import-name-soft_unicode-from-markupsafe/)

I tried running `sudo pip3 install markupsafe==2.0.1` but it was unsuccesful. Any help is appreciated.